# How to modify vue-cli's vue-loader to update transformAssetsUrl

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I'm using vue-cli 3.0.1.

I wish to update the transformAssetsUrl option, but am not sure how to do this.(https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/options.html#transformasseturls)

I'm not exactly sure what I should put in the chainWebpack part of vue.config.js

Comment: What you need from the documentation is the part about [modifying the options of a loader](https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-loader). The first example should be exactly what you what concerning modifying the `vue-loader`, tapping the args, and then returning your new properties.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy that is exactly what I needed thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments above, this is described here - https://cli.vuejs.org/guide/webpack.html#modifying-options-of-a-loader

For my particular case I wanted to update the transforassetsurls to handle v-img tags.  Below is how I did this.

```js
// vue.config.js
config.module
  .rule('vue')
  .use('vue-loader')
    .loader('vue-loader')
    .tap(options => {
      return {
        transformAssetUrls: {
          "v-img": 'src'
        }
      });
```

Comment: That doesn't appear to show an example which answers your own question. You asked how to update the 'transformAssetsUrl' option on vue-loader, but the answer shows a totally unrelated example (changing the file size limit of url-loader).

Comment: @AdamMcCann You're right.  I updated the answer.  Thanks for the heads up.  I think I copy/pasted the code from the link above instead of my version.